# Order of drawing layers / Maintaining scale when toggling layers/

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

There are two things my professor would like me to correct in my code.  The first one being I need the RU rest layers to be drawn over top of my floodplain layer so all the rest layers are visible.  And second there seems to be a something in my code that resets the scale of the map when you toggle the floodplain layer and I would prefer if this did not happen.  Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Toggle</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
     </style>
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r172/trunk/arcgislink/src/arcgislink.js"></script>

    <script>

var overlay;
var map;
var url;
var dynamap;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.1276, -80.56895),

  };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

url = 'http://geog-grant.radford.edu/arcgiscloud/rest/services/RU/MapServer';
    dynamap = new gmaps.ags.MapOverlay(url);

overlay = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.radford.edu/kblakemore/KML_Layer_Severity/KML_Floodplain_Radford/doc.kml'
  });


}

function toggleFloodplain() {
 overlay.setMap(overlay.getMap() ? null : map);
}

function toggleRUrest() {
    dynamap.setMap(dynamap.getMap() ? null : map);
}


window.onload = initialize;


    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
     <div id ="panel">

      <p> Floodplains Radford, Virginia </p>
       <input id= "toggle" type="checkbox" value="toggleFloodplain"     onclick="toggleFloodplain();"> Floodplains </input>
       <input id= "toggle" type="checkbox" value="toggleRUrest" onclick="toggleRUrest()">Toggle     RUrest</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what did you try? what went wrong? what research have you done? this site isn't meant to do the work for you...

Comment: Sorry didn't mean for it to come off that way.  I'm merely seeking a direction to go in. This is my first time coding with js and html (very little experience with java but it helped me to create the functions I implemented for the toggle). I've looked at the javascript api for google maps and also the arcGIS api for javascrpit. I've found a "reorder layers in map service" documentation in the arcGIS javascript. It read "To re-order layers, click and drag a layer name to a new position. When a layer name is dropped to a new position in the list, a request is made to get an updated map image.

Comment: I tried this and it did not change anything.  Is it because one layer is a dynamic map layer and the other is a KML?

Comment: Your question about preserving the viewport (not zooming to fit the KmlLayer) is to use the `preserveViewport:true` option of the [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerOptions).  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh2d16rx/) (that is a duplicate of several other similar questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use another map-pane for the dynamap.

The map-pane is hardcoded in the used library(line 2796):

```
panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
```

use e.g. `markerLayer` instead of `overlayLayer`

To be able to change it you must either change the library directly or overwrite `MapOverlay.prototype.onAdd` (that's the function where the pane will be assigned)